# Downward slope but Spearman correlation coefficient is positive and vice versa

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, spearman-rho, scatterplot, example

Why the slope and the Rho value not the same?  For examples, graph **H-DSI** shows downward slope but the Rho value is **positive** (P value=0.9603; r=0.009867). Hope someone can explain it. Thank you.

| H | DSI |
| --- | --- |
| 45.94 | 0.00 |
| 40.15 | 53.99 |
| 42.98 | 25.31 |
| 40.22 | 55.99 |
| 40.71 | 50.67 |
| 39.47 | 44.66 |
| 39.55 | 53.99 |
| 57.38 | 0.00 |
| 45.21 | 62.66 |
| 56.26 | 28.67 |
| 45.18 | 61.33 |
| 46.45 | 66.00 |
| 44.79 | 66.68 |
| 42.67 | 71.34 |
| 65.32 | 0.00 |
| 48.09 | 87.33 |
| 64.00 | 42.00 |
| 49.05 | 79.99 |
| 53.99 | 70.66 |
| 53.40 | 74.00 |
| 50.04 | 79.33 |
| 78.45 | 0.00 |
| 50.95 | 98.67 |
| 73.45 | 43.99 |
| 59.63 | 88.00 |
| 61.05 | 76.66 |
| 61.85 | 78.00 |
| 61.93 | 83.33 |

[image]

Comment: Spearman's rho measures monotonic correlation not linear correlation and being rank based, will not be pulled down very much by the low outliers in thr fist plot. If you plot the ranks - which is what you're calculating the correlation of, you'll see the relationship looks different. Do you have the data available to paste in? (Use code formatting for the data)

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to do code formatting for the data, but I include the table for the data.

Comment: Thanks, that's sufficient. Why are there fewer DSI values in the second set? Why are so many of the DSI values really close to multiples of 1/3?

Comment: Thank you for highlighting that, I've checked it. Please ignore the second set as there is some mistake.

Comment: I'd have to redo my plots to remove it; it's still useful for illustrating how Spearman correlation can change sign from the Pearson correlation.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spearman correlation is not a linear correlation of the data, but a linear correlation of a transformed version of the data -- specifically, the correlation of the rank-transformed data. It doesn't "see" what you show in your plots. (The second plot has been removed from the question, but I will leave it in my answer as it still serves to illustrate the points being made.)

[image: Plots of DSI versus H and DSI versus IGR, and plots of the same variables after a rank transform.]

In the plot of DSI vs H, the low points (especially the zeros) that are on average further right than the bulk of the data "pull" the regression line down. If those points were absent the line would slope up. Rank transforming these variables reduces the impact of the low points (the rightmost ones are relatively less influential - the highest H-values are less distant - *and* the corresponding low DSI values are less discrepant). At the same time a group of points in the upper left quadrant are transformed to be much further to the right. Consequently, the line in the transformed data has a slope that is essentially flat (but *just* positive).

In the plot of DSI vs IVGR, the four very low DSI values are now omitted, so they are not there pulling on this regression line. Here the six rightmost IVGR values have DSI values mostly above the mean of DSI rather than below, so this line slopes up. Again, the rank transform reduces the impact of these influential points and the correponding line on the transformed data is essentially flat (but *just* negative).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I really appreciate it. For the zero value, it's actually the DSI for the control (free from disease, thus DSI = 0).  Is it okay if I remove the control from the plot?

Comment: That really depends on what the plot is supposed to be showing you -- but I would at least indicate the controls with a different colour.

Comment: Thank you, this really solve my problem.